# How to start `powercfg.exe -energy` from a .NET app?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, process, powercfg

When I

```
using (var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
         FileName = "powercfg.exe",
         Arguments = "-energy",
         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
         UseShellExecute = false,
    }
})
{
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

It outputs:

> A biblioteca de Diagnóstico de Eficiência de Consumo de Energia (energy.dll) não
>    pôde ser carregada.

Translated to English:

> The Energy Consumption Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) couldn't be loaded.

Even when running as admin.

Comment: The problem only occurs when executing the app from .NET, when I invoke it from the command line it runs normally

Comment: Why do you have UseShellExecute = false?

Comment: @dthorpe `RedirectStandardOutput = true` requires `UseShellExecute = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I cannot duplicate your results; I get the results file as expected.  But if it helps, perhaps my testing parameters will help you narrow down what may be the culprit in your environment:

- Running Visual Studio 2010 as Administrator
- Targeted .NET 4 Client Profile
- Compiled both x86 and Any CPU binaries
- Computer is running Windows 7 x64

Comment: the culprit is the argument "-energy" which uses the "energy.dll". I didn't include this argument at the time you tested it, but now I edited the question. My environment is the same as yours.

Comment: I did put that argument in there which is why I revised my answer.  It applies as written.

Comment: It began to work, but I don't know what caused the problem or solved it

Answer (score 0):

Set the `WorkingDirectory` to the path `energy.dll` and `powercfg.exe` is located.