# energy.dll is missing, when starting powercfg from code

Tags: c#, process.start, powercfg

This is an addition to an **Old Thread**

[How to start `powercfg.exe -energy` from a .NET app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821342/how-to-start-powercfg-exe-energy-from-a-net-app)

I'm trying to run `powercfg /BatteryReport`. It throws an error

> "The Energy Consumption Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) couldn't be loaded."

This is the code I used:

```
using (Process JS = new Process())
        {
            string output = "\"" + runfrom + "\\" + msn + ".html\"";
            JS.StartInfo.Arguments = (@" /k powercfg /BatteryReport /output " + output);
            JS.StartInfo.FileName = (@"cmd.exe");

            MessageBox.Show(JS.StartInfo.FileName + JS.StartInfo.Arguments);
            JS.Start();
            JS.WaitForExit();
        }
```

I receive the `energy.dll` error as mentioned above. First I ran the `powercfg command` directly. I changed to the script above, to see whats going on.
When I do a `DIR` on `Windows\System32` in the `command box`, opened by my code, there are 2672 files in there. When I open up a new `command box` and do a DIR on `Windows\System32`, there are 3866 files. Any idea what kind of witchcraft this is?

Comment: 32-bit versus 64-bit and file system redirection. What looks like `System32` can sometimes by `SysWow64` (confusingly, that's the directory that's used for 32-bit processes)

Comment: Thanks Damien. That was exactly the hint I needed. Based on your answer, I came to this post, that solved the problem.
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100390/file-getting-copied-to-syswow64-instead-of-system32>